# Can I change color of Android DatePicker (Mode - Spinner) selected item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am developing an application where I need to show a dialog with a DatePicker in it. Now my designs are such that the DatePicker should be Spinner mode as was prior to Material Design. I want it to look something like this - [image: This is a dialog in which datepicker will be in the middle]

I'm trying to make my custom view of the dialog and then use datepicker spinner in android but then I am not able to change the color of the selected number to Red. How to change the color of the numbers selected in between to red as shown in the image?
Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score -1):

The color depends on the theme set on the `Dialog` used to inflate the layout. 
Set up a basic theme like this:

```
<style name="PickerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
     <item name="colorAccent">@color/error_red</item>
    </style>
```

where the `colorAccent` attribute applies the color you want to your `DatePicker`